# Is there laser operating at megahertz?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, frequency, microwaves

I have tried to find a laser with working frequency at megahertz by Google but failed. Is there exist one?

Comment: There are antennas operating in MHz - GHz range, for more radiation directivity such as in laser, one might use a horn antenna or phased array.

Comment: Why would you want a laser? Spectral purity and long coherence length - normal rf sources can do it. Power - you can get powerful rf sources using normal electronics

Comment: Thanks ! Do you mean phased array can not only collect but also radiate high directivity EM wave, [Pierre Polovodov](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/70892/pierre-polovodov)?

Answer (score 0):

Given the frequency range, it cannot be called [*laser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser) (*light amplification via stimulated emission of radiation*), since the frequency is not in the optical range (see [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum))... it can even hardly be called [*maser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maser) (*microwave amplification via stimulated emission of radiation*), since it is not in the microwave range... so the best would be to google for *radio frequency amplification via stimulated emission* or *quantum generator of radio waves* or something like that.

Related:
[Quantum description of radio antenna](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/668970/247642)
[Does a radio receiver "collapse" a radio wave function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737511/247642)

**Remark:**
The way I understand the question is that we are talking not simply about absorption and emission of radio frequency photons on a quantum level, but about a laser-like devices - i.e., amplification of these photons via stimulated emission and possibly also their emission as a free field. Already in microwave range, the small frequency of the photons (compared to room temperature) requires using cryogenic technology and confining photons to waveguides (possibly superconducting waveguides.) See, e.g., [The bright side of Coulomb blockade](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0131).

Comment: This question might also be of help: [Lightest photon ever detected](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247505/the-lightest-photon-ever-detected)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a check.

Comment: Laser is used for for frequencies not in the visible range as shown specifically in your linked wiki. You can see this directly in one image showing a wide variety of lasers along with their location on the spectrum. Man of which lie outside it.

Comment: @Triatticus I didn't say that laser emits visible light - it is a generator in the *optical range*, which has higher frequencies than*microwave range*, which are in turn higher than radio frequencies.